# Text in other languages when hovering over icons in side navbar

Tags: quarto

I am developing a book in a language other than English. I need to know if it's possible to modify the tooltip text that appears when hovering over the icons in the side navbar, specifically for the 'Share' and 'Source Code' options.

While the tooltip text for the 'Reader Mode' and 'Light/Dark Theme' icons correctly adapts to different languages, this isn't the case for the aforementioned icons.

[image]

I have the following elements in the yalm:

```yaml
project:
  type: book

lang: pt-BR

book:
  sharing: [twitter, linkedin, facebook]
  site-url: https://luifrancgom.github.io/estatistica-descritiva-R-1ed/
  repo-url: https://github.com/luifrancgom/estatistica-descritiva-R-1ed
  repo-branch: main
  issue-url: https://github.com/luifrancgom/estatistica-descritiva-R-1ed/issues
  reader-mode: true

format:
  html:
    theme: 
      light: cosmo
      dark: darkly
```

Where according to [Quarto Localization](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/tree/main/src/resources/language) `pt-BR` is supported with the following [translation](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/language/_language-pt-BR.yml).

Is there a way to modify the tooltip text for the 'Share' and 'Source Code' options?

Comment: Included as a Q&A in https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/8125

Comment: Check out https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/8145 where it was switched as a feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by Charles Teague (quarto developer) via https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/pull/8169. Also translations for spanish and brazilian portuguese where added in `quarto v1.4.542`